# Scraping an Angular website with selenium and C# returns the angular script, not the rendered web page

Tags: ajax, angular, selenium

This seems to be by design as far as I can tell. Selenium can see the initially loaded HTML, but not the HTML after it's been massaged. I've tried IE, Chrome and PhantomJS and they all show the same behavior. So does the built-in Chrome debugger, until you inspect an element on the page, you can't query any of the rendered HTML.

I'm looking for any suggestions about how to scrape the web page. The only option I see right now is finding the chrome process, triggering the inspector, clicking inside, then running the Javascript. Needless to say, this sounds fragile.

I also haven't been able to find anything on capturing the Ajax calls from selenium so I can make them and capture the JSON. When tried copy / paste from the chrome network tab into selenium I got a missing application block message.

Does anyone have any other advice?

Since I can replicate the issue in the chrome debugger, I don't see posting code as useful. It looks like a design decision.

Ralph

Comment: Are you making Selenium wait until angular is fully loaded? Maybe add a generous timeout for starters, then you can possibly get more advanced if needed.

Comment: Yes. As I said, I see the same behavior in the Chrome console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I wasn't able to do things in a straightforward way. Instead, I used Selenium to do the login and navigate to the page, then use windows API calls to click inside the window send ^a^c to copy the data and an absolute location to click on the button to go to the next page.

The site is set up so that ^a^c copies the raw data for this site. I don't know if that's standard for Angular or not.

Fragile, but it works.